# DirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl method always fails

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

I tried to get access information of 'current user' folder.
But this code always return "method failed with unexpected error code 3, InvailedOperationException".

Here is my code

```
string CurrentUserName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
var Info = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\users\\"+ CurrentUserName);
var Security = Info.GetAccessControl();
```

Comment: What is the value of `CurrentUserName`? On my machine, it's of the form `DOMAIN\username`, which gives a folder that doesn't exist..

Comment: You're better off using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)`, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I thought 'CurrentUserName' should get username only, not for Domain\username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Blorgbeard. Here is the alternative code what you told. 
It works perfectly.

```
 string CurrentUserName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);

 var Info = new DirectoryInfo(CurrentUserName);

 var Security = Info.GetAccessControl();
```